# How deep it goes with session variable in Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

`Session` variable can be accessed in `Rails controller`. In our app, method A (a method in controller) calls method B (in a module) and session is available in B. My question is how deep it goes before session variable disappears. For example, if B calls method C, is `session` still available in C?

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing, if the module happens to be a helper rails automatically gives it access to context from the controller. If this was just a plain old ruby module which is not included it would not have access to session (which is a method belonging to the controller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if method B is in a module which is included into the controller via something like `include MyModule` that's why the session variable is available within that method. If you test it out, and call out to a class not included in the controller, it shouldn't be available, but when you include a module into the controller you have access to that scope.

Comment: If module C included in Module B which is also included in a controller. does methods in module C have access to session?

Comment: yep it will, just tested it out (wasn't sure myself) BUT if they're included into a model or domain class or something that doesn't have access to session, they would not.